# How can i convert an NPN transistor to PNP transistor?

Tags: transistors, npn, pnp

Could anybody help me by providing a circuit diagram for converting a NPN transistor to a PNP transistor?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Right after you tell me how to convert my diodes to resistors.

Comment: Do you believe it could be done? The answer to your question and the following is the same! 'Could anybody help me by providing a circuit diagram to get negative voltage from the positive terminal of a cell?'

Comment: @PlasmaHH Much easier than the other way around. ;-)

Comment: I suppose, in a certain circuit you want to replace a npn with a pnp transistor, correct?

Comment: Do you still want it to work?

Comment: Another guess: are you looking for a circuit with an NPN that acts like a PNP? Or do you want a method to convert a circuit with an NPN to a circuit with a PNP?

Comment: You need an atomic chisel and a molecular hammer.  And good eyesight.

Answer (score 3):

Giving you the benefit of the doubt- of course you cannot change the doping of the semiconductor, but you may be able to convert a circuit that uses NPN transistors to use PNP.

If you reverse the supply voltage, flip any diodes (including LEDS) and electrolytic caps you may be able to adapt the circuit. There are, however, many parts for which no reversed part exists- almost all chips with more than two pins (voltage regulators-sometimes possible), SCRs, depletion mode MOSFETs etc, so circuit design changes would be necessary (and maybe not sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to convert an NPN transistor to a PNP transistor.

If you have a circuit that requires a PNP transistor, but you only have NPNs, you cannot build the circuit. In some cases, it may be possible to convert an entire circuit from using PNP to using NPN (or vice versa). But that means changing the circuit, not the parts.